# Is there some way where I could query this Map where I will only retrieve the data of those less than 5?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have these documents inside the collection.

**Document 1**

[image]

**Document 2**

[image]

For every document in these collections, these `items` of the `map` would have different values. Is it possible to query those `items` that have a number below 5?

For example:

- desctiption1
- Item1 - 5
- Item6 - 5

And then for the description 2:

- description2
- Item 2 - 5
- Item3 - 4

So far, this is what I have done:

```
 const getData = async () => {
      const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, "collectionDesc"));
      const q = query(querySnapshot, where("map", "<=", 5));
      const arr = [];
      querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        arr.push({
          ...doc.data(),
          id: doc.id,
        });
      });
      if (isMounted) {
        console.log(arr)
      }
    };
```

Comment: I don't think it's possible to use `where` in this query, because it doesn't iterate over the contents of "map" but just compares the value directly. So you would have to retrieve all documents in `collectionDesc` and then filter the results out in the callback when going over the snapshot results. Or you could make "map" a sub-collection - then you would be able to query directly against Firestore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As b2m9 commented, this is not possible as your query compares the `map` field to the primitive value `5` you pass, which will never be equal.

To implement this use-case, you'll have to add additional data to your document, like a field that tracks the lowest value in the `map` field. Say you call this `lowestValueInMap` and its value is `4` based on your sample document, you can then query it with:

```
query(querySnapshot, where("lowestValueInMap", "<=", 5));
```